# EF6 Code First - Self-referencing configure navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create this simple **Categories** table:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Children")]
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And I want -as coded- to have navigation properties in both sides, but that doesn't work. There is a problem in **Children** property.

Whenever I query **Categories** from the DbContext I get:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

(I tried with and without **[InverseProperty]**)

Any tips? Thanks...

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I found the problem is in another navigation property in this entity which I didn't list in the code above. The question now makes no sense and I flagged it to be deleted, but thanks @TanguyB and @Pavel Bory for help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try intializing the ICollection in a constructor in your class. I had some problems with that too and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you do not have corrupted / inconsistent data in your database? Because I tried to implement the same Model class Category as you did and it works. I tried to create instances of categories and link them and then reload them from the database and it works. Try to delete data from database and try it again. If problem occurs even after that, can you post your sample of code for DbContext class and piece of code where do you use it?